# How to populate jTable using MS ACCESS on a button event?

Tags: java, jtable, apache-commons-dbutils

Here is my Code:
Its not displaying any data on Jtable please help me guys:

Connection con=null;

```
ResultSet rs=null;

PreparedStatement ps=null;
    try{
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=c:\\a.accdb");
          String sql="Select * from expenses";
              ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
       Table_Expenses.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);
```

By

```
rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

EDIT:

Now you failing to call your query

Replace

```
Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=c:\\a.accdb");
```

By

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=c:/a.accdb");
```

OR

```
ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

By

```
ps=co.prepareStatement(sql);
```